# How to import Settings from WebStorm in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

Half of my team uses WebStorm and half uses VSCode. So there is always spacing issue in code. So I would like to import their WebStorm settings to my VSCode.

I already have the `setting.jar` file from WebStorm. How do I import it in VSCode?

Can anyone help regarding this?

Comment: Do you use ESlint (if you use javascript)? Do you use an editorconfig file?

Comment: Yes, I use ESLint. I can't find an editorconfig file, so i guess no.

Comment: You should then look inside the eslint config to enforce and auto-fix the spacing issues (there are many different rules), it can occur when you save the file for example. It might also be related to the plugin which handles eslint config not properly working.